# Java equivalent of C#'s Rfc2898DerivedBytes

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, encryption, rfc2898

I was wondering if anyone have tried to do an equivalent of

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(secret, saltValueBytes);
byte[] secretKey = key.GetBytes(16);
```

in Java. Where secret is a string(password), and saltValueBytes is, well, a salt in byte array.

I've tried stuff, but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Can you please tell how you solved it with the library in the chosen answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this implementation](http://rtner.de/software/PBKDF2.html) by means of a Google search but I have never used it.

> **A free Java implementation of RFC 2898
>   / PKCS#5 PBKDF2**
>
> There seems to be no small and freely
>   available Java implementation of RFC
>   2898 / PKCS#5 available. Small as in
>   only a few source files, with trivial
>   compile and no dependencies, free as
>   in LGPL.
>
> Given the availability of HMacSHA1 in
>   the standard SUN JCE cryptographic
>   provider, such an implementation is
>   quite simple and can be derived from
>   the RFC description quite literally.
>   My code is a clean-room implementation
>   with only the RFC as its basis.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Not quite what I was looking for since I'd really like a regular Java implementation using the normal libraries

Comment: I know it - it's really a bummer that there isn't a direct equivalent.

Comment: @ElChe I know this is old, but since you chose this as an answer, can you tell how you ended up writing the equivalent of those 2 lines you asked about (using the linked implementation)?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is late to the game, but Java 6 and up *does* have a built-in PBKDF2 implementation.

```
int dkLen = 64;
int rounds = 1000;
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec("Some password".toCharArray(), "SomeSalt".getBytes(), rounds, dkLen * 8);
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
byte[] out = factory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
```

The list of [Java 6 Security Enhancements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements.html) claims comparability with PKCS#5, and through my own (cursory) testing it does appear to produce correct PBKDF2 keys.

Comment: The problem with this is that you only have SHA1. You can't change it to use anything newer. Even if you accept that, I still could not make this library produce hashes that matched other (non-Java) reference libraries.

Comment: This only uses HMAC-SHA1 because that's all that RFC2898 mentions, and Op was asking for a Java equivalent of Rfc2898DeriveBytes. Also, not sure what you're testing against, but this absolutely does produce correct PBKDF2 keys. Verified this against Rfc2898DeriveBytes, and the [PBKDF2 test vectors](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt).

Answer (score 4):

This one works for me. 
I still am in disbelief that a standard implementation of an RFC2898-compliant PBKDF2 is not present in the JRE.  I think I must be looking in the wrong places. The name confusion (RFC2898 PKCS5 PBKDF2) doesn't help.

```
// PBKDF2.java
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// RFC2898 PBKDF2 in Java.  The RFC2898 defines a standard algorithm for
// deriving key bytes from a text password.  This is also called 
// "PBKDF2", for Password-based key derivation function #2.
//
// There's no RFC2898-compliant PBKDF2 function in the JRE, as far as I
// know, but it is available in many J2EE runtimes, including those from
// JBoss, IBM, and Oracle.
//
// It's fairly simple to implement, so here it is. 
// 
// Author: Admin
// built on host: DINOCH-2
// Created Sun Aug 09 01:06:57 2009
//
// last saved: 
// Time-stamp: <2009-August-09 11:11:47>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// code from Matthias Gartner
//
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

package cheeso.examples;


import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class PBKDF2
{
    public static byte[] deriveKey( byte[] password, 
                                    byte[] salt, 
                                    int iterationCount, 
                                    int dkLen )
        throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
               java.security.InvalidKeyException
    {
        SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec( password, "HmacSHA1" );
        Mac prf = Mac.getInstance( "HmacSHA1" );
        prf.init( keyspec );

        // Note: hLen, dkLen, l, r, T, F, etc. are horrible names for
        //       variables and functions in this day and age, but they
        //       reflect the terse symbols used in RFC 2898 to describe
        //       the PBKDF2 algorithm, which improves validation of the
        //       code vs. the RFC.
        //
        // hLen denotes the length in octets of the pseudorandom function output
        // dklen the length in octets (bytes) of the derived key. 

        int hLen = prf.getMacLength();   // 20 for SHA1
        int l = Math.ceil( dkLen/hLen ); //  1 for 128bit (16-byte) keys
        int r = dkLen - (l-1)*hLen;      // 16 for 128bit (16-byte) keys
        byte T[] = new byte[l * hLen];
        int ti_offset = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
            F( T, ti_offset, prf, salt, iterationCount, i );
            ti_offset += hLen;
        }

        if (r < hLen) {
            // Incomplete last block
            byte DK[] = new byte[dkLen];
            System.arraycopy(T, 0, DK, 0, dkLen);
            return DK;
        }
        return T;
    } 


    private static void F( byte[] dest, int offset, Mac prf, byte[] S, int c, int blockIndex ) {
        final int hLen = prf.getMacLength();
        byte U_r[] = new byte[ hLen ];
        // U0 = S || INT (i);
        byte U_i[] = new byte[S.length + 4];
        System.arraycopy( S, 0, U_i, 0, S.length );
        INT( U_i, S.length, blockIndex );
        for( int i = 0; i < c; i++ ) {
            U_i = prf.doFinal( U_i );
            xor( U_r, U_i );
        }

        System.arraycopy( U_r, 0, dest, offset, hLen );
    }

    private static void xor( byte[] dest, byte[] src ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < dest.length; i++ ) {
            dest[i] ^= src[i];
        }
    }

    private static void INT( byte[] dest, int offset, int i ) {
        dest[offset + 0] = (byte) (i / (256 * 256 * 256));
        dest[offset + 1] = (byte) (i / (256 * 256));
        dest[offset + 2] = (byte) (i / (256));
        dest[offset + 3] = (byte) (i);
    } 

    // ctor
    private PBKDF2 () {}
}
```

Comment: To use it: `byte[] myKey = PBKDF2.deriveKey(...);`

Comment: **Note**, this implementation is incorrect! According to RFC, `l` is defined as `ceil(dkLen/hLen)` and not as max of the two.

Comment: @Cheeso: Just a note, `Math.ceil( dkLen/hLen )` will not produce the correct values because dkLen and hLen are both `ints`. They need to be converted to `double` before doing the division. Math.ceil(64/20)=3.0, while Math.ceil((double)64/(double)20)=4.0.

Comment: @Cheeso I've decided to stick with [this implementation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/api/org/jboss/seam/security/crypto/PBKDF2Engine.html). I checked it with RFC and it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved Cheeso's code for working with HMacSHA256 or HMacSHA512 by adding overloaded deriveKey(). With this change, the code was run with PKDF2-HMAC-SHA512 test vectors from
[PHP Crypt lib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib/blob/master/test/Data/Vectors/pbkdf.custom.test-vectors) which resulted in 6 failures out of 100 test cases.

```
// PBKDF2.java
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// RFC2898 PBKDF2 in Java.  The RFC2898 defines a standard algorithm for
// deriving key bytes from a text password.  This is also called 
// "PBKDF2", for Password-based key derivation function #2.
//
// There's no RFC2898-compliant PBKDF2 function in the JRE, as far as I
// know, but it is available in many J2EE runtimes, including those from
// JBoss, IBM, and Oracle.
//
// It's fairly simple to implement, so here it is. 
// 
// Author: Admin
// built on host: DINOCH-2
// Created Sun Aug 09 01:06:57 2009
//
// last saved: 
// Time-stamp: <2009-August-09 11:11:47>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// code from Matthias Gartner
//
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

package cheeso.examples;


import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class PBKDF2
{
    public static byte[] deriveKey(byte[] password,
                                   byte[] salt,
                                   int iterationCount,
                                   int dkLen)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException
    {
        return deriveKey("HmacSHA1", password, salt, iterationCount, dkLen);
    }

    public static byte[] deriveKey(String hmacAlgo,
                                   byte[] password,
                                   byte[] salt,
                                   int iterationCount,
                                   int dkLen)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException
    {
        SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(password, hmacAlgo);
        Mac prf = Mac.getInstance(hmacAlgo);
        prf.init( keyspec );

        // Note: hLen, dkLen, l, r, T, F, etc. are horrible names for
        //       variables and functions in this day and age, but they
        //       reflect the terse symbols used in RFC 2898 to describe
        //       the PBKDF2 algorithm, which improves validation of the
        //       code vs. the RFC.
        //
        // dklen is expressed in bytes. (16 for a 128-bit key, 32 for 256)

        int hLen = prf.getMacLength();   // 20 for SHA1
        int l = Math.max( dkLen, hLen); //  1 for 128bit (16-byte) keys
        int r = dkLen - (l-1)*hLen;      // 16 for 128bit (16-byte) keys
        byte T[] = new byte[l * hLen];
        int ti_offset = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
            F( T, ti_offset, prf, salt, iterationCount, i );
            ti_offset += hLen;
        }

        if (r < hLen) {
            // Incomplete last block
            byte DK[] = new byte[dkLen];
            System.arraycopy(T, 0, DK, 0, dkLen);
            return DK;
        }
        return T;
    } 


    private static void F( byte[] dest, int offset, Mac prf, byte[] S, int c, int blockIndex ) {
        final int hLen = prf.getMacLength();
        byte U_r[] = new byte[ hLen ];
        // U0 = S || INT (i);
        byte U_i[] = new byte[S.length + 4];
        System.arraycopy( S, 0, U_i, 0, S.length );
        INT( U_i, S.length, blockIndex );
        for( int i = 0; i < c; i++ ) {
            U_i = prf.doFinal( U_i );
            xor( U_r, U_i );
        }

        System.arraycopy( U_r, 0, dest, offset, hLen );
    }

    private static void xor( byte[] dest, byte[] src ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < dest.length; i++ ) {
            dest[i] ^= src[i];
        }
    }

    private static void INT( byte[] dest, int offset, int i ) {
        dest[offset + 0] = (byte) (i / (256 * 256 * 256));
        dest[offset + 1] = (byte) (i / (256 * 256));
        dest[offset + 2] = (byte) (i / (256));
        dest[offset + 3] = (byte) (i);
    } 

    // ctor
    private PBKDF2 () {}
}
```

Comment: what does it mean if 6 out of 100 test cases "fail"? Is the code somehow buggy - or are the test vectors wrong?