# Working Rfc2898DeriveBytes.Pbkdf2 in Java

Tags: cryptography, hash, java, .net, pbkdf2

I have some passwords hashed with  C# using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes.Pbkdf2(bytes,src,5000,HashAlgorithmName.SHA1,24)` (an older implementation) and would like to port this code to java.

However I don't seem to get the two hashes to be the same.
I have no idea why and how.
I tried multiple implementations and they produce the same results in Java, different from C# .

I also posted on https://github.com/skradel/Zetetic.Security/issues/1 since the original code is using `Zetetic.Security` package.

C# code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string _ALGORITHM = "pbkdf2";

        public static string PrintBytes(byte[] byteArray)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder("new byte[] { ");
            for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
            {
                var b = byteArray[i];
                sb.Append(b);
                if (i < byteArray.Length - 1)
                {
                    sb.Append(", ");
                }
            }
            sb.Append(" }");
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static Program()
        {
            CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(Zetetic.Security.Pbkdf2Hash), _ALGORITHM);
        }



        public static string EncodePassword(string pass, int passwordFormat, string salt)
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
            var src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
            byte[] inArray;
               var hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create(_ALGORITHM);
                    Console.WriteLine("hashAlgorithm is KeyedHashAlgorithm");
                    var algorithm2 = (KeyedHashAlgorithm)hashAlgorithm;
                    Console.WriteLine("algorithm2.Key.Length == src.Length " + src.Length);
                    algorithm2.Key = src;
                    Console.WriteLine("Compute hash" + algorithm2.HashSize);
                    inArray = algorithm2.ComputeHash(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Bytes " + inArray.Length + PrintBytes(inArray));
            Console.WriteLine("Salt " + PrintBytes(src));


            var pass2 = Rfc2898DeriveBytes.Pbkdf2(bytes,src,5000,HashAlgorithmName.SHA1,24);
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(pass2)); 
            return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var password = args[0];
            var salt = args[1];
            var format = Int32.Parse(args[2]);

            Console.WriteLine("==Convert password '" + password + "' using salt '" + salt + "' and format '" + format + "' ==");
            Console.WriteLine(EncodePassword(password, format, salt));

        }
    }
}
```

And the Java code:

```
byte[] saltBytes = saltStr.getBytes(UTF_8);
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec("my-secret".toCharArray(), saltBytes, 5000, 192);
Key secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded())
```

Besides the official Java implementation, I also tried 2 more: https://rtner.de/software/PBKDF2.html and the one from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1360237/638331 .
I get the same hash in Java.

I have tried Zetetic implementation and the one from C# standard library and I am getting the same result there, but not as in Java.

**UPDATE:**
The Java version is compatible with https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp .
I could generate the same hash in Java as in the above JS app using the same params: 5000 iterations, PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1, 192 bits and my salt.

(BTW, the website sends data to a server, so don't use any real passwords / data)

The hash is different than the one in C# .

**UPDATE**: Example run for C#

```
$ ./bin/Debug/net7.0/pw-encoder mama dNuhxK7K5SaJk2M5HqwyNA== 1 
==Convert password 'mama' using salt 'dNuhxK7K5SaJk2M5HqwyNA==' and format '1' ==
hashAlgorithm is KeyedHashAlgorithm
algorithm2.Key.Length == src.Length 16
Compute hash192
Bytes 24new byte[] { 25, 111, 18, 46, 51, 211, 183, 94, 103, 93, 54, 65, 64, 46, 0, 105, 76, 70, 33, 212, 150, 24, 185, 168 }
Salt new byte[] { 116, 219, 161, 196, 174, 202, 229, 38, 137, 147, 99, 57, 30, 172, 50, 52 }
GW8SLjPTt15nXTZBQC4AaUxGIdSWGLmo
GW8SLjPTt15nXTZBQC4AaUxGIdSWGLmo
```

Using the same password and values with Java local code and  https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp using parameters: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1, 16 bit Initial Vector[ dNuhxK7K5SaJk2M5HqwyNA==] , 5000 iteration and 192 bits for dkLen
gives me the hash bellow:

```
pR/jfNDZoVqCiXQ7YTGR3g/h7O3J/sMR
```

Comment: I have also asked on Microsoft Q&A https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1420745/rfc2898derivebytes-pbkdf2-compatible-with-java-ver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encodings differ: In the C# code the salt is Base64 decoded, in the Java code it is UTF-8 encoded. In the C# code the password is `Unicode` encoded specifying UTF16-LE in .NET, in the Java code it is UTF-8 encoded.

Fix: Use the same encodings in the Java code as in the C# code.

However, there is a small problem: The JCA/JCE implementation of PBKDF2 performs a UTF-8 encoding internally, s. [`getPasswordBytes()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-22%2B23/src/java.base/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBKDF2KeyImpl.java#L72). There is neither a possibility to change the encoding nor one that directly process a byte sequence instead of a `char[]`, s. [`PBEKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html#constructor-summary). Workaround: Apply  another library, e.g. [`PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/r1rv76/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator.java) from BouncyCastle. Here is a sample implementation:

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.PBEParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA1Digest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
...
String saltStr = "dNuhxK7K5SaJk2M5HqwyNA==";
String passwordStr = "mama";
byte[] salt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(saltStr);                                      // Fix: Base64 decode salt
byte[] password = passwordStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);                      // Fix: UTF-16LE encode password
PBEParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA1Digest());    // Fix: Apply a PBKDF2 implementation that can handle byte sequences
generator.init(password, salt, 5000);
byte[] key = ((KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedParameters(192)).getKey(); 
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key)); // GW8SLjPTt15nXTZBQC4AaUxGIdSWGLmo
```

This code provides the same result as the C# code.

---

Remark regarding the UTF-16LE encoding: One could come up with the idea of converting the initial string from which the C# code generates the UTF-16LE byte sequence in such a way that a UTF-8 encoding generates the same byte sequence:

```java
String passwordStr = new String("<your password>".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

However, this does not work in general, but only in some cases, as not every UTF-16LE byte sequence is UTF-8 decodable.
For instance, it is possible for characters with Unicode code points < 128 (ASCII characters), so it would work for `mama`, but not for `mama§` (which would be corrupted during conversion). Also, the converted password contains whitespaces (which is not critical here, as the password is not printed out).

Comment: Thank you!  It's amazing how (seemingly little) things matter! 

Here is something to make your day better  https://soundcloud.com/user-452914422/queen-bohemian-rhapsody?si=c6e7b87ab56c4ad691b24f83adaeafdf&utm_source=clipboard&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=social_sharing (no yt since they have gone crazy with ads)